# Why does react component return multiple elements?

Tags: reactjs

How many elements does React component return? One or multiple?
My prof says multiple but I don't get it

Comment: A react component can return one element,  multiple elements or no elements (`null`).

Comment: The following article might help. https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#summary

Answer (score 0):

wrap your nodes in a <React.Fragment> (aka <></>) like below, you can return multiple, otherwise, only 1 root node can be returned

```
export default () => {
    return <React.Fragment>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </React.Fragment>
}
```

or

```
export default () => {
    return <>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </>
}
```

in earlier version which doesn't have React.Fragment, you need to create a HOC